# What is special about android:inputType="textPersonName" for EditText

Tags: android

I tried

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
```

I realize it can accept any characters. So, what is special having `android:inputType="textPersonName"`, compared to not having it?

Answer (score 41):

The difference is that if you use "textPersonName", the user can not insert new lines (the enter button is not showed)

Comment: How do you get that benefit? is there any reference so i can read about InputType?

Answer (score 20):

Spelling check is not done when using `android:inputType="textPersonName"` but it is done in `textCapWords`.

So if you use `textPersonName`  there won't be red underline for names but first letter of each name (firstname, middlename, lastname etc) won't be capitalized.

so best solution is combining both with an or
that is  `android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"`.

now there won't be red underline for name and first letter would be capitalized also

Comment: `textPersonName` must have included `textCapWords` so that it reflects what it says.

Answer (score 0):

i am testing on android 5.0.1 and i insert a edittext with "textPersonName" input type and other edittext with "text" input type and in the two example the enter button is not showed. i really dont see differences between these input types.

regards