# InputType = PersonName?

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView object that's purpose is to type in the name of a person. I looked at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) and saw that `textPersonName` is an input type. So I selected that input type, thinking that it would do what I wanted.

However, this input type does not capitalize the first letter. As people's names start with capital letters, I found this to be very odd. Is this intentional, or a design oversight on Google's part?

In any case, I have selected `textCapWords` as the new input type to make sure every word starts capitalized. Will there be any disadvantage to using this input type for a person's name? What are the benefits of using `textPersonName` as the input type?

Comment: I haven't played around with textPersonName myself. But some names don't always have a capital. I guess stuff like von, af etc. (European). As for the benefits, no idea.

Comment: I think capitalized by default is best as it seems far more likely that someone will want to put in a capitalized name.

Comment: Phantom down-voters; please give constructive criticism. If you give me feedback on my question then I can improve it. At least explain why you think this question does not conform to stack overflow's standards.

Comment: `textPersonName` also does not stop user type in numbers or other characters which cannot appear in a person's name. To enable user to put only valid chars, using `android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` helped.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can combine the inputType attributes using an `|` (or) operator.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

> The type of data being placed in a text field, used to help an input method decide how to let the user enter text. The constants here correspond to those defined by InputType. Generally you can select a single value, though some can be combined together as indicated. Setting this attribute to anything besides none also implies that the text is editable.
>
> Must be one or more (separated by '|') of the following constant values.

So to combine the benefits of `textPersonName` with `textCapWords`, simply set the input type using this syntax:

```
android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16910454) gives a brief explanation of the benefits of using textPersonName for a name entry field.

Comment: this is not correct, as input_type should can not be used on TextView

Answer (score 13):

`inputype` attribute in `EditText` widget: *(tested on Android 4.4.3 and 2.3.3)*

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/et_test" android:inputType="?????"/>
```

- inputType: **textLongMessage**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: yes. Case: lowercase. Suggestion: yes. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **textFilter**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: yes. Case: lowercase. **Suggestion: no**. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **textCapWords**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: yes. **Case: Camel Case**. Suggestion: yes. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **textCapSentences**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: yes. **Case: Sentence case**. Suggestion: yes. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **time**. Keyboard: numeric. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: no. **Suggestion: no**. Addition chars: :
- inputType: **textMultiLine**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. **Enter button: nextline**. Has emotion: yes. Case: lowercase. Suggestion: yes. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **number**. **Keyboard: numeric**. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: no. Suggestion: no. **Addition chars: nothing**
- inputType: **textEmailAddress**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. Enter button: Send/Next. **Has emotion: no**. Case: lowercase. **Suggestion: no**. Addition chars: **@** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **(No type)**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. **Enter button: nextline**. Has emotion: yes. Case: lowercase. Suggestion: yes. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **textPassword**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: no. Case: lowercase. **Suggestion: no**. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **text**. Keyboard: Keyboard: alphabet/default. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: yes. Case: lowercase. Suggestion: yes. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **textShortMessage**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. **Enter button: emotion**. Has emotion: yes. Case: lowercase. Suggestion: yes. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **textUri**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: no. Case: lowercase. **Suggestion: no**. Addition chars: **/** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **textCapCharacters**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: yes. **Case: UPPERCASE**. Suggestion: yes. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything
- inputType: **phone**. **Keyboard: numeric**. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: no. **Suggestion: no**. Addition chars: *** # . -  / () W P N , +**
- inputType: **textPersonName**. Keyboard: alphabet/default. Enter button: Send/Next. Has emotion: yes. Case: lowercase. Suggestion: yes. Addition chars: **,** and **.** and everything

**Note:** `Auto-capitalization` setting as shown in the following screenshot will change the default behavior (True is default, textCapWords will work as expected. False will override textCapWords)

[image: Auto-capitalization setting]

**Note 2:** In the `Numeric keyboard`, ALL numbers are English 1234567890.

**Note 3:** `Correction/Suggestion` setting overrides the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> In any case, I have selected textCapWords as the new input type to
>   make sure every word starts capitalized. Will there be any
>   disadvantage to using this input type for a person's name?

Don't seems to be any problem here as your just changing the input type specifying it as a initial letter to Capital but it will allow multiple lines to be entered.This can be a disadvantage when you want only a single line with a person name.

> What are the benefits of using textPersonName as the input type?

Single line entry in the textfield is the advantage for using text input as textPerson.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to have single line entry with `textPerson`, but also have the first letter of every word capitalized? (Best of both worlds?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705776/how-to-capitalize-every-letter-in-an-android-edittext for you `TextWatcher` will be helpful you will need to use it according to your need hope this is helpful

Comment: @Teifi I think you can combine input types with the `|` operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv1;

EditText et1;

Button bt1; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String s=et1.getText().toString();

    //char s1=s.charAt(0);


     if (s.length() <= 1) {
            s = s.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            s = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +s.substring(1);
        }        

     tv1.setText(s);

}
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spelling check is not done when using `android:inputType="textPersonName"` but it is done in `**textCapWords**`

So if you use `textPersonName`  there won't be red underline for names but first letter of each name(firstname, middlename, lastname etc) won't be capitalized

so best solution is combining both with an or
that is  `android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"`

now there wont be red underline for name and first letter would be capitalized also