# why can I enter numbers in textPersonName?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to type only letters on the keyboard, no numbers, I used this method and it doesn't work, why?

```
                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Comment: Take a look at [what-is-special-about-androidinputtype-textpersonname-for-edittex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731961/what-is-special-about-androidinputtype-textpersonname-for-edittext?lq=1)

Comment: Thank u, but how can I display only letters?

Comment: _...how can I display only letters?..._ [how-to-create-edittext-accepts-alphabets-only-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361497/how-to-create-edittext-accepts-alphabets-only-in-android)

Comment: I saw that answers but I thought that is another way

Comment: Why do you think that that should prevent numbers? Are you assuming that no one has numbers in their name?

Comment: I think yes, who has numbers in name?

Comment: R2D2. That's robo-descrimination i guess)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create EditText accepts Alphabets only in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361497/how-to-create-edittext-accepts-alphabets-only-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/name"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:digits="qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM"
/>
```

need to test though

Comment: This would fail for non-english words. For example, alphabets like à, è, ù